# Remove all the <u> and <a> tags from within all <div> tags of a class using BeautifulSoup or re

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-re

I am trying to remove `<u>` and `<a>` tags from all the DIV tags that has class "sf-item" from an HTML source because they are breaking the text while scraping from a web url.

(for this demo, I have assigned a sample html string to the BeautifulSoup method - but it would ideally be a web URL as source)

So far I have tried using re with below line - but am not sure how to specify a condition in re such that - remove only the substring between all the `<u` `/u>` only within DIV tags of class sf-item

```
data = re.sub('<u.*?u>', '', data)
```

Also tried removing all `<u>` and `<a>` tags from the entire source using below line, but somehow it doesn't work. Am kind of unsure how to specify all the `<u>` and `<a>` tags only within DIV tags with class sf-item.

```
for tag in soup.find_all('u'):
    tag.replaceWith('')
```

Appreciate if you could please help me achieve this.

Below is the Sample Python code that works -

```
from re import sub
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

data = """
<div class="sf-item"> The rabbit got to the halfway point at   
<u><a href="https://DummyLocationURL/"> here </a></u> However, it couldn't see the turtle. 
</div>
<div class="sf">
<div class="sf-item sf-icon">
<span class="supporticon is"></span>
</div>
<div class="sf-item"> He was hot and tired and decided to stop and take a short nap. 
</div>
<div class="sf-item"> Even if the turtle passed him at 
<u><a href="https://DummyLocationURL/">Link</a></u>. he would be able to race to the finish line ahead of 
<u><a href="https://DummyLocationURL/">place</a></u>, he just kept going.
</div>
"""

# data = re.sub('<u.*?u>', '', data)  ## This works for this particular string but I cannot use on a web url
# It would solve if I can somehow specify to remove <u> and <a> only within DIV of class sf-item

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

for tag in soup.find_all('u'):
    tag.replaceWith('')

fResult = []
rMessage=soup.findAll("div",{'class':"sf-item"})

for result in rMessage:
    fResult.append(sub("&ldquo;|.&rdquo;","","".join(result.contents[0:1]).strip()))

fResult = list(filter(None, fResult))
print(fResult)
```

Output that I get from above code is

```
['The rabbit got to the halfway point at', 'He was hot and tired and decided to stop and take a short nap.', 'Even if the turtle passed him at']
```

But I need the output as below -

```
['The rabbit got to the halfway point at here However, it couldnt see the turtle.', 'He was hot and tired and decided to stop and take a short nap.', 'Even if the turtle passed him at Link. he would be able to race to the finish line ahead of place, he just kept going.']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BeautifulSoup has a builtin method for getting the visible text from a tag (i.e. the text that would be displayed when rendered in a browser). Running the following code, I get your expected output:

```
from re import sub
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

data = """
<div class="sf-item"> The rabbit got to the halfway point at   
<u><a href="https://DummyLocationURL/"> here </a></u> However, it couldn't see the turtle. 
</div>
<div class="sf">
<div class="sf-item sf-icon">
<span class="supporticon is"></span>
</div>
<div class="sf-item"> He was hot and tired and decided to stop and take a short nap. 
</div>
<div class="sf-item"> Even if the turtle passed him at 
<u><a href="https://DummyLocationURL/">Link</a></u>. he would be able to race to the finish line ahead of 
<u><a href="https://DummyLocationURL/">place</a></u>, he just kept going.
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

rMessage=soup.findAll("div",{'class':"sf-item"})

fResult = []

for result in rMessage:
    fResult.append(result.text.replace('\n', ''))
```

That will give you the proper output, but with some extra spaces. If you want to reduce them all to single spaces, you can run fResult through this:

`fResult = [re.sub(' +', ' ', result) for result in fResult]`